# Azure B2C Orchestration Error AADB2C90108

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, postman, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to get an access token using the password grant type in a `POST` request from Azure AD B2C. Once sent it gets the below error

> "error": "server_error",
> "error_description": "AADB2C90108: The orchestration step '1' does not specify a CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId when one was expected.\r\nCorrelation ID: .............\r\n"

I have tried with other authentication types like client credintials which is not working azure ad b2c but getting below error

> "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
> "error_description": "AADB2C90086: The supplied grant_type [client_credentials] is not supported.\r\nCorrelation ID:

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The usual reason you get this is that it's missing e.g.

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" 
                   Type="SendClaims"
                   CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
```

Are you using a custom policy? What type of policy are you using?

As the error message says, "client credentials" is not yet supported in B2C.

Comment: No I think, our internal team had configured standard Signup and Signin policy